# SmartMenus not working properly on Chrome because of display:flex;

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

For a new project, I am using **Bootstrap 3** with the **[SmartMenus](http://smartmenus.org)** addon for the submenus.

My problem is that on **Chrome** (v 58), the caret on the links that have a submenu is disappearing on load, the submenus are showing on click instead of hover, and they are not closing when another is opened.

I have found where this issue comes from though. The class `.sm-collapsible` is applied to my `ul.navbar-nav` element on load. 
BUT, it's applied only if the `ul.navbar-nav` element has a `display:flex;` AND on Chrome. I tried to reproduce my layout with `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` and it's also not working.

So this isn't particularly a flex problem, but **it comes from the layout** and it messes the JavaScript.

I have no idea why or how it's even possible.

You can check an online version here : https://lesdeuxvagues.com/laloupe (hover/click on **Catalogues** to see the issue)

Thanks in advance... i'm really stuck here.

**EDIT** 
I just found the responsible JS line that adds the `.sm-collapsible` class. Here it is: 
`obj.isCollapsible = function() { return !/^(left|right)$/.test(this.$firstLink.parent().css('float')‌​);};`

It returns true all the time on Chrome (when display:flex; is not commented) but only on mobile for Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the editor of the plugin, since it seemed like a problem with the way the plugin is coded, and it's fixed now. Display:flex; isn't creating a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try changing the `ul.navbar-nav` to `display: block;` in CSS (you can modify bootstrap.less:  `#header #navbar > ul { display: block; }` or overwrite it in your own less file) or modify the plugin's JS by looking for function responsible for adding `.sm-collapsible` and removing that action.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Well, setting it to `display:block;` wouldn't solve my issue, because I need to use `justify-content:space-between;` for my layout. 

I actually just found the responsible function that adds this class : `obj.isCollapsible = function() {
                        return !/^(left|right)$/.test(this.$firstLink.parent().css('float'));
                    };`. It returns true on chrome but not on firefox. I have no idea how this line works...

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
obj.isCollapsible = function() {
    return (!/^(flex)$/.test(this.$firstLink.parent().parent().css('display'))) && (!/^(left|right)$/.test(this.$firstLink.parent().css('float')));
};
```

**NOTE:** `display: flex` must be on `ul.navbar-nav`